# google sheets : hover dropdown list in cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 aims but first would do. 1: Hover dropdown list in google sheets cell (hover = list opens up) and syntax please . 2: acts on last item hovered over in dropdown list (e.g. a number in another cell) .Basically trying to do away with need for clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> hover = list opens up

This is not featured by Google Sheets and cannot be programmatically installed.

You may refer to triggers, all we can is:

> **onOpen(e)** runs when a user opens a spreadsheet, document, or form that
> he or she has permission to edit.
>
> **onEdit(e)** runs when a user changes a
> value in a spreadsheet.
>
> **onInstall(e)** runs when a user installs an
> add-on.
>
> **doGet(e)** runs when a user visits a web app or a program sends
> an HTTP GET request to a web app.
>
> **doPost(e)** runs when a program sends
> an HTTP POST request to a web app.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/